# UiNavigationbar buttons not responding after upgrade to iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, svg, uinavigationbar

After upgrading to iOS 11 and to XCode9 my App's NavigationBar buttons (left and right) are not responding. It is working well in previous version but not in iOS 11. can anybody help me or have faced the same issue. My App is in Objective c language.

```
**//here is code for leftbarbutton**

UIImage *backSVG = [UIImage imageWithSVGNamed:@"backarrow32" targetSize:CGSizeMake(25, 25) fillColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

UIBarButtonItem *notifyButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:backSVG style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(handleBackButton)];

[notifyButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = notifyButton;

**//Rightbar buttons are**

 UIBarButtonItem *rightbar1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:
 [UIImage imageWithSVGNamed:@"rightbar1" targetSize:CGSizeMake(21, 21) 
 fillColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self 
 action:nil];

  [rightbar1 setAction:@selector(handlerightbar1Action)];

  UIBarButtonItem *rightbar2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:
  [UIImage imageWithSVGNamed:@"rightbar2" targetSize:CGSizeMake(21, 21) 
  fillColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
  target:self action:nil];

  [rightbar2 setAction:@selector(handlerightbar2Action)];

   [rightbar1 setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -30, 0, -50)];

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray 
   arrayWithObjects:rightbar2, rightbar1, nil];
```

Comment: Your problem might be because of the setImageInsets, try removing it.

Comment: Tried removing setImageInsets but its still the same.

Comment: I see that you have an extension 'imageWithSVGNamed' , edit your question and add this extension, so we can help you.

Comment: this report could help you: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85601

Answer (score -1):

Is this navigation bar you added in interface builder or it is from navigation controller (either pushed or root view controller)?

If you can attache an image of the UI view controller from interface builder, it will give more details of the issue.